# Почему не срабатвает window.location.href

Tags: javascript

вот форма

```
<form id="w0" method="get" action="найти">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Поиск" value="" name="query">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button onclick="window.location.href=this.form.action+'-'+this.form.query.value" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
         </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

получаю при нажатии на button вот такой адрес `http://film.lc/%найти?query=запрос`
если я делаю так

```
<form id="w0" method="get" action="найти">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Поиск" value="" name="query">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button onclick="alert(window.location.href=this.form.action+'-'+this.form.query.value)" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
             </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

То через некоторое время, если не нажимать на окно алерт window.location.href сработает и я получу вот такой адрес [http://film.lc/найти-запрос](http://film.lc/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81). 
Почему на первой форме не срабатывает не подскажите и как с этим бороться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `button` стоит `type="submit"`. При клике на кнопку в данном случае происходит отправка формы, поэтому кажется, что обработчик *onclick* в котором меняется location не срабатывает.

В случае алерта, основной цикл обработки тормозится при выполнении алерта, параметр, которого вычисляется и меняется location.

Не совсем понятен смысл такого обработчика. Либо нужно заменить `type="submit"` на `type="button"`, либо убрать *onclick*